# LinearProgramming returns an invalid null solution that apparently doesn't satisfy constraints without any warning

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

While searching to answer the question

- [Solving the magic backyard puzzle with MMA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56298/solving-the-magic-backyard-puzzle-with-mma/108655#108655)

at some time I composed a set of arguments for `LinearProgramming` that apparently is not handled correctly. Running this code:

```
args = {cost, m, bs, vr, vd} = 
   Import["http://www.dropbox.com/s/73iz8t8ivakazvt/LinearProgrammingIssue.m?dl=1"];
sol = LinearProgramming @@ N@args
```

gives an invalid `{0, 0, 0, ....., 0}` solution that apparently doesn't satisfy the constraints

```
MapThread[#3[#1, #2] &, {m.sol, bs[[All, 1]], 
  bs[[All, 2]] /. {0 -> Equal, 1 -> GreaterEqual, -1 -> LessEqual}}]
Sign[m.sol - bs[[All, 1]]] == bs[[All, 2]]
```

> {True, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, False, 
>   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
>   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
>   False, False, True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, 
>   True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>   True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>   True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, 
>   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False}
>
> False

without raising any warning.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

---

After @DanielLichtblau's comment, I also tried to reproduce with `Minimize` and `Maximize`.

```
args = {cost, m, bs, vr, vd} = 
   Import["http://www.dropbox.com/s/73iz8t8ivakazvt/LinearProgrammingIssue.m?dl=1"];

Module[{x, vars, constraints, objective, ranges, domains, N = N},
 vars = Array[x, Length@cost];
 objective = N@cost.vars;
 constraints = 
  MapThread[#3[#1, #2] &, {N@m.vars, N@bs[[All, 1]], 
    bs[[All, 2]] /. {0 -> Equal, 1 -> GreaterEqual, -1 -> LessEqual}}];
 ranges = MapThread[LessEqual @@ Riffle[#2, #1] &, {vars, vr}];
 domains = Thread[vars \[Element] N@vd];
 Minimize @@ {{objective, {constraints, ranges, domains}}, vars}
 ]
```

If I apply `N` as in `LinearProgramming` (so `Module[{..., N=N}, ...]`) the answer is immediate and still wrong.

If I don't apply `N` (so `Module[{..., N=Identity}, ...]`) Mathematica starts computing but I didn't have the patience to check if/when something happens.

I suspect this issue can be related to very big numbers in the cost vector (they are not machine precision *`Integer`*). They can converted into machine precision `Real`, but I'm not sure if a `Real` cost vector can be combined with `Integer` variables in a `LinearProgramming`/`Minimize` problem.

Comment: It's a bug. If one sets this up to use `Maximize` it should work correctly, albeit more slowly.

Comment: Thanks @DanielLichtblau. I updated the question adding an header and the bugs tag. Hope to have done it right.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Apparently, on my machine, also `Minimize`/`Maximize` gives a wrong answer.

Comment: Do you have the input for `Minimize` (or handy code to generate it)?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Added some code and info.