# How to tell Solve[] to satisfy as many constraints as it can?

Tags: equation-solving

Is there any way to tell `Solve` (or something similar) to return values for variables that solved as many constraints as it happened to satisfy?

#### Edit:

I had trouble finding a small example that wasn't trivial, but I finally did. Here's one:

```
Solve[{{-1 + Abs[q2 (-(7/4) + t1)], q1, -1 + Abs[q1 (-(7/4) + t2)], 3 + q2} == 0,
       {t1, t2} >= 7/4},
      {t1, t2, q1, q2}]
```

The kind of output that I **want** (I don't care if it's not unique; I can deal with that):

```
{{t1 -> 25/12, t2 -> Indeterminate, q1 -> 0, q2 -> -3}}
```

The output that I **get**, but **don't want**:

```
{}
```

Comment: Please paste in a minimal example.

Comment: @JackLaVigne: I'm afraid if I post an example then people are going to suggest a method that solves that particular example and not the actual problem...

Comment: @JackLaVigne: But here's a trivial example: `Solve[{x^2 + 1 == 0, y^2 - 1 == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]` gives no solution, while `Minimize[{Abs[x^2 + 1] + Abs[y^2 - 1]}, {x, y}, Reals]` finds a solution for `y` which is still useful to me. (If you read the above, **please** don't tell me to separate the equations and solve them independently. I know I can do that for this particular example, but that also completely misses the point of my question, which I think is clear.)

Comment: If your system is indeed overdetermined, the `ArgMin[]` route would be more expedient than forcing `Solve[]` to do your bidding. FWIW, your last snippet gives the same output as `With[{p = 1}, ArgMin[Norm[Subtract @@@ {x^2 + 1 == 0, y^2 - 1 == 0}, p], {x, y}, Reals]]`. Do you really need to use the $1$-norm? That is a more difficult problem than minimizing with respect to the usual $2$-norm.

Comment: @J.M.: The 1-norm was only to reduce my typing in the comment box (I guess that backfired!)... and right, I realize `ArgMin` is a solution, but I'm asking if there is a way to use `Solve`. `ArgMin` is solving a harder problem than the one I need, because I really don't need to minimize errors with respect to unsatisfiable constraints. If there isn't a way then that's a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @J.M.: I actually found an example, could you please reopen the question? Also try my example to see why I can't always use `ArgMin` either (`NArgMin` sometimes works, but I want something symbolic...).

Comment: I reopened your question because you made effort to provide an example, but coming back to this an hour later I don't understand the example you provide.  How is `{t1 -> 25/12, t2 -> Indeterminate, q1 -> 0, q2 -> -3}` a solution to that system?  Are your sublists meant to be `Or`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: It's a vector equality to zero, so "and". If you try evaluating it as `Function[{t1, t2, q1, q2}, {-1 + Abs[q2 (-(7/4) + t1)], q1, -1 + Abs[q1 (-(7/4) + t2)], 3 + q2}][25/12, Indeterminate, 0, -3]` you see the vector becomes `{0, 0, Indeterminate, 0}` which is pretty close to all zeros.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you're after now.  I'll have to think about that.

Answer (score 2):

If your equations and constraints are linear (or can be expressed as linear), and if a machine precision solution is enough you can use functions like `LinearProgramming` or `NMinimize` to get a solution:

```
M = 50;
NMinimize[{
  z1 + z2 + z3,
  {
   -1 + Abs[q2 (-(7/4) + t1)] == 0,
   q1 == 0,
   -1 + Abs[q1 (-(7/4) + t2)] >= 0 - M*z3,
   -1 + Abs[q1 (-(7/4) + t2)] <= 0 + M*z3,
   3 + q2 == 0,
   t1 >= 7/4 - z1*M,
   t2 >= 7/4 - z2*M,
   z1 \[Element] Integers, 0 <= z1 <= 1,
   z2 \[Element] Integers, 0 <= z2 <= 1,
   z3 \[Element] Integers, 0 <= z3 <= 1
   }
  },
 {t1, t2, q1, q2, z1, z2, z3}
 ]
```

> {2., {t1 -> 2.08333, t2 -> 549.224, q1 -> 0, q2 -> -3., z1 -> 1, z2 -> 1, z3 -> 0}}

Basically, you introduce some binary ($0-1$) decision variables $z_i$ and one or more costant $M$ big enough so that you can rewrite the desired $i$ constraint in a way that when $z_i$ is $1$ constraint is always satisfied. You then minimze the sum of $z_i$.

More references to `LinearProgramming` in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108655/16267) and

- [Solving the magic backyard puzzle with MMA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56298/solving-the-magic-backyard-puzzle-with-mma?lq=1)

and another example of "conditional constraints", here:

- [Puzzle with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108655/16267)

With `NMinimize` you can also handle some non-linear constraint. Unfortunately `Minimize` is not available because:

> Minimize::mixdom: Exact optimization with mixed real and integer variables is not yet implemented.

You can of course try to implement by yourself this strategy (a search on a suitable tree) to get an exact answer. If there are only few "conditional constraints" you can also try to `Solve` for all possible $(z_1z_2\ldots)$ until you find a solution. In this case, with at most $2^3=8$ cases is not too difficult.

---

As an idea of how we can do a search on a tree, start building a suitable tree. This tree is such that the binary digits of the node are used to identify a subset of constraints. There is also an interesting ordering in `DepthFirstScan` visit order; see the picture.

```
vt[n_] := Module[{l, p},
  l = Range[0, 2^n - 1];
  p = FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ 
    Replace[IntegerDigits[l, 
      2], {a : 0 ..., 1, b___} :> {a, 0, b}, {1}];
  TreeGraph[l, p, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
   VertexLabels -> Thread[l -> IntegerString[l, 2, n]]]
  ]
vt[4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A simple (?), but far from optimal, search function is:

```
ssolve[eqns_, cons_, vars_, dom : _ : Reals] :=
 Module[{n, t, m, c, s, l, w, r},
  n = Length@cons;
  t = vt[n];
  s = Association@Thread[VertexList[t] -> False];
  m = -\[Infinity]; c = Indeterminate;
  r = {};
  DepthFirstScan[t, 0,
   "DiscoverVertex" -> Function[{u, v, d},
     Which[
      s[v], s[u] = True,
      d > m,
      With[{sol = 
         Quiet@Solve[
           Join[eqns, Pick[cons, IntegerDigits[u, 2, n], 1]], vars, 
           dom]},
       If[sol == {}, s[u] = True,
        c = u; r = sol; m = d
        ]]
      ]]];
  {Pick[cons, IntegerDigits[c, 2, n], 1], r}
  ]
```

A sample (all your equations and inequalities are considered optional):

```
eqns = Thread /@ {{-1 + Abs[q2 (-(7/4) + t1)], 
      q1, -1 + Abs[q1 (-(7/4) + t2)], 3 + q2} == 0, {t1, t2} >= 7/4} //
   Flatten
vars = {t1, t2, q1, q2};
ssolve[{}, eqns, vars, Reals]
```

The return value is a list with the set of constraints fulfilled and the return value of `Solve`.

```
{{-1 + Abs[q2 (-(7/4) + t1)] == 0, -1 + Abs[q1 (-(7/4) + t2)] == 0, 
  3 + q2 == 0, t1 >= 7/4, 
  t2 >= 7/4}, {{t1 -> ConditionalExpression[25/12, q1 > 0], 
   t2 -> ConditionalExpression[(4 + 7 q1)/(4 q1), q1 > 0], 
   q2 -> ConditionalExpression[-3, q1 > 0]}, {t1 -> 
    ConditionalExpression[25/12, q1 < 0], 
   t2 -> ConditionalExpression[(-4 + 7 q1)/(4 q1), q1 < 0], 
   q2 -> ConditionalExpression[-3, q1 < 0]}}}
```

I didn't fully tested the code but the basic idea should work, and should be more efficient than testing all the possible subsets of constraints. The use of built-in function `DepthFirstScan` is easy, but unfortunately at present doesn't allow to really skip the visit of a subtree.

*Edit. In the way I used `DepthFirstScan`, nodes are not processed in DFS order. To fix this problem, I think a more involved code is required. At this point, I don't really see any reason to build a `TreeGraph` and use `DepthFirstScan`. I think it's better to use another strategy. I'll try to post an update when I have time.*

Comment: Thanks but they're definitely nonlinear... even the example I gave isn't linear.

Comment: @Mehrdad As you can see `NMinimize` handle some nonlinear constraint. And the example given can be expressed as linear. You can combine this approach with `Solve` and a search on binary trees or, more simply, with a full search to get what you want.