# Putting as many expressions as possible equal to zero

Tags: equation-solving

Say I have a list of expressions involving many different variables. I would like to see how many of the expressions I can set equal to zero thereby solving for some of the variables in terms of the rest.

For example, say I have the following array,

`A={a^2-b, b-a^2+1}`

and I would like Mathematica to try to set as many of the components of `A` to zero as possible. `Solve[A==0, {a,b}]` will give an empty set since obviously both components of `A` cannot be zero at the same time. I would like Mathematica to solve the first component `b->a^2` and ignore the second.

How can I tell it to ignore those expressions that lead to a contradiction and keep going down the list of expressions, setting them equal to zero if possible?

Comment: This seems similar to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109643).

Comment: Perhaps [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) `Solve` into the equations and thread the solutions generated at each step.  When there is no solution, `Solve` returns `{}` and the post-processing replacement rule `{} -> {#}` simply replaces the no-solution `{}` with the current solution.  (`Solve` automatically choose which variable to solve for.  If that is not acceptable, then the question needs to specify how the variables are to be chosen.)

```
annihilateIfPossible[exprs_] := 
 Fold[Function[{sols, expr}, 
   Sequence @@ (Solve[expr == 0 /. #] /. {s__Rule} :> 
          Join[#, {s}] /. {} -> {#}) & /@ sols],
  {{}},
  exprs];

annihilateIfPossible[{a^2 - b, b - a^2 + 1}]
(*  {{b -> a^2}}  *)

annihilateIfPossible[{a^2 - b, b - a^2 + 1, c - b^2 + a}]
(*  {{b -> a^2, c -> a (-1 + a^3)}}  *)

annihilateIfPossible[{a^2 - b^2, b - a^2 + 1, c - b^2 + a}]
(*
  {{b -> -a, a -> 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), c -> 1/2 ( 1 + Sqrt[5] + 2 a^2)},
   {b -> -a, a -> 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]), c -> 1/2 ( 1 - Sqrt[5] + 2 a^2)},
   {b ->  a, a -> 1/2 ( 1 - Sqrt[5]), c -> 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5] + 2 a^2)},
   {b ->  a, a -> 1/2 ( 1 + Sqrt[5]), c -> 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5] + 2 a^2)}}
*)
```

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.