# Why does FromDigits transpose its argument (sometimes)?

Tags: functions, syntax

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}} ;   

FromDigits /@ Transpose@ a == FromDigits @ a
(* True *)
```

The only "strange" syntax I've found in the docs is

[image: doc-item]

But it doesn't seem related to this behavior. Or at least I don't see how.

Note that when there are only two lists, the second one is considered as base 10 "exponents" and threaded upon.

```
FromDigits @ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
(* {120, 1200} *)
```

that comes from the syntax above

```
FromDigits @ {{1, 2}, 3}
(* 120 *)
```

Comment: (1) There is an ambiguous case (two lists of equal length) that gets resolved in a certain way. Else the input such as `{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}` becomes `100*{1,2}+10*{3,4}+1*{5,6}`, that is, each sublist is treated as a "digit".

Comment: (2) This being "Malicious Friday", I may have to vote to close. Otherwise I'll have to play a prank on some hapless colleague.

Comment: Failing to mention threading over *n* seems a serious omission in the docs.  (Maybe the writers noticed the ambiguity and left it out hoping no one would notice..)

Comment: @george2079 Probably :)  Daniel's explanation is quite clear, but I'm inclined to keep the question instead of deleting it.  Opinion?

Comment: There are a number of functions that "auto-thread" without mention in the documentation. I don't know if the reason for that has to do with possibilities of ambiguity. But I should mention that this particular case is not actually one of auto-threading. It is simply treating a case where digits themselves are lists. That this cannot be done when given two lists of the same length is a (perhaps unfortunate) consequence of the design.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It's probably trivial now for me (after your comment :) ) That "unfortunate consequence" was exactly what baffled me and originated the question. Thanks a lot for your explanation

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94832/193). BTW,perhaps you can come with a faster alternative there.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau BTW, to be able to use this syntax I was forced to check the lengths to be sure they have more than 2 elements :)

Comment: Ah. Good motivating example. (Though the "real" way to do that digits problem is with integer or constraint programming).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  My first try was the naive `vars = Array[x, 10];
obj = Array[10^# &, 4, 0].vars[[1 ;; 4]];
c1 = And @@ Thread[0 <= vars <= 9];
c2 = Unequal[Sequence @@ vars];
c3 = obj - Array[10^# &, 4, 0].vars[[5 ;; 8]] - 
    Array[10^# &, 2, 0].vars[[9 ;; 10]] == 0;
const = {c1, c2, c3};
Maximize[{obj, const}, vars, Integers]` . But it runs out of memory.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Indeed I tried to solve that puzzle as always with LP...