# Given list of associations, generate a list of all common associations

Tags: list-manipulation, logic

Given a list of parameters and associated values, how can I generate a list of all common associations?
For instance, given

```
list = {{AA, 3}, {AB, 2}, {AB, 4}, {BA, 2}, {BA, 5}, {BB, 6}};
```

I want to obtain

```
{{AA, 3}, {AB, {2, 4}}, {BA, {2, 5}}, {{AB, BA}, 2}, {BB, 6}}
```

(Edit)
Both answers from both kglr and mef will break down under certain circumstances, eg., 
When

```
list = {{{15, "->", 15}, 3}, {{15, "->", 15}, 8}, {{16, "->", 16}, 2}, {{16,"->", 16}, 3}, {{16, "->", 16}, 4}, {{16, "->", 16}, 5}, {{16, "->", 16}, 6}, {{16, "->", 16}, 7}, {{16, "->", 16}, 8}}
```

the solution from kglr gives

```
{{{15, "->", 15}, {3, 8}}, {{16, "->", 16}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}, {{{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, 3}}
```

and the solution from mef gives

```
{{{15, "->", 15}, {3, 8}}, {{16, "->", 16}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}, {{{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, 8}}
```

where the desired result is

```
{{{15, "->", 15}, {3, 8}}, {{16, "->", 16}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}, {{{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, {3, 8}}}
```

(Edit #2)
It may be helpful if I describe what I’m actually looking at. Given a list labeled graphs of order n which includes a mix of graphs which are pairwise either isomorphic or non-isomorphic, and each graph is uniquely identified by a number

```
listGi ={1,2,3,…};
```

Each labeled graph Gi has a Kirchhoff matrix which is invariant to some transformation from the permutation group.

```
KirchhoffMatrix[Gi] == Pj.KirchhoffMatrix[Gi].Transpose[Pj];
```

Each element of the permutation group is also uniquely identified by a number,

```
Pj = {1,2,3,…};
```

I then have a list of each Gi “associated” with an element of the permutation group which leaves its Kirchhoff matrix invariant (I ignore the identity element of the permutation group). For example, in a particular mix of graphs which are pairwise either isomorphic or non-isomorphic I have

```
listA = {{{1 -> 1}, 17}, {{2->2}, 17}, {{3->3}, 24}, {{4->4}, 24}, {{5->5}, 8}, {{6->6}, 17}, {{7->7}, 8}, {{8->8}, 2}, {{8->8}, 7}, {{8->8}, 8}, {{8->8}, 17}, {{8->8}, 18}, {{8->8}, 23}, {{8->8, 24}, {{9-9}, 6}, {{9-9}, 8}, {{9-9}, 10}, {{9-9}, 15}, {{9-9}, 17}, {{9-9}, 19}, {{9-9}, 24}};
```

What I want is a list of the Gi’s which are invariant to common Pj’s. And the list of all the P’j that leave KirchhoffMatrix[Gi] invariant which are not specified in the first instance. (LLIAMnYP describes this more rigorously with his analogy of sub-matrices.)  For input listA above my desired output is:

```
{{{8->8}, {9->9}, {8, 17, 24}}, {{8->8}, {2,7,8,17,18,23,24}}, {{9->9},{6,8,10,15,17,19,24}}, {{{3->3},{4->4},{8,8},{9,9}}, 24}, {{{5->5},{7->7},{8->8},{9->9}}, {8}}, {{{1->1},{2->2},{6->6},{8->8},{9->9}}, 17}}
```

This solution is correctly obtained by LLIAMnYP in his answer. 
I thought I could get my point across with a single example, but I was wrong! When I repeatedly pointed out where proposed answers did not do what I wanted, I was accused of continuously changing the problem. Not true, I had to change the specific example of listA to show that the proposed answers were not solving the problem. My many thanks to LLIAMnYP for his insight and diligence to finally understand and solve my question. 
I am surprised that the solution proved to be as difficult as it was. And, again, I thought I could communicate the problem with a single simple example.
Mr.Wizard proposed a solution which did not give the correct result. However his proposed solution did give results which were not part of my original quest, which, however, I found interesting in retrospect. His solution included those Pj which were unique to a Gi and were not otherwise included in the output list. For instance, an example from listA above, {Pj} = {2,7,18,23} are unique to {8->8}. If anyone could pose a solution which does the same thing as LLIAMnYP’s answer and included these unique “associations”, I would be grateful.
I can visually compare an example input listA (one that is not too long, anyway) with the output list and see if it produces my desired output. My desired result is not ambiguous, apparently it is just tricky to describe.

Comment: This problem resembles factoring common multipliers out. What I do not understand, is why `{AB, {2, 4}}` and `{BA, {2, 5}}` *and* `{{AB, BA}, 2}` are present. Would just `{AB, 4}, {BA, 5}, {{AB, BA}, 2}` not work?

Comment: I think I understood what you need, see if my answer works for you.

Comment: Philipp, my friend: Is this a guessing game or what? How about a _precise_ problem description instead of this trial and error game?

Comment: Henrik, I really don't mean to play games. I don't see the problem as at all vague or especially difficult. In my response to Mr.Wizard I pose given list = {{"dog", 6}, {"dog", 8}, {"dog", 10}, {"cat", 3}, {"cat", 
    8}, {"cat", 11}, {"bird", 3}, {"bird", 6}, {"bird", 8}, {"bird", 
    10}, {"bird", 11}, {"bird", 12}}; my desired output is {"dog" -> {6, 8, 10}, "cat" -> {3, 8, 11}, 
 "bird" -> {3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12}, {"dog", "bird"} -> {6, 8, 
   10}, {"dog", "cat", "bird"} -> {8}, {"cat", "bird"} -> {3, 8, 
   11}, {"bird"} -> {12}}

Comment: Phillip, more than half a dozen not completely dumb people are wasting their time to guess what you might mean. Really, there _must_ be something vague about your question. Examples are _not_ a form of a precise problem description. For a start: What do you mean with "all common associations"? There are actually no associations at all in your input examples.

Comment: See LLlAMnYP's answer.

Comment: @Henrik I understand your frustration, since this problem has many edge cases. Part of the answer is to ask the right question, which can be hard when the edge cases are so plentiful. I think we can show some compassion here.

Comment: "my desired output is {"dog" -> {6, 8, 10}, "cat" -> {3, 8, 11}, "bird" -> {3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12}, {"dog", "bird"} -> {6, 8, 10}, {"dog", "cat", "bird"} -> {8}, {"cat", "bird"} -> {3, 8, 11}, {"bird"} -> {12}} ".  Is {"bird"} -> {12} really the desired output?

Comment: @tomd {"bird"}-> {12} type data was not originally what I asked for. But MrWizard  was able to pull it out and I wont sniff at it if a proposed answer  includes it.

Comment: Well, having it there makes absolutely no sense to me. '12' appears in the list  "bird" -> {3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12}, and I cannot find this example in Mr Wizard's answer.  I think it is reasonable to require clarification: you either want it there or you don't. (see @Henrik Schumacher comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
commonAssociations[list_] := 
 Module[{assoc = Merge[Association@*Rule @@@ list, Union], keys, vals,
    result},
  keys = Rest@Subsets[Keys@assoc];
  vals = Intersection @@@ Map[assoc, keys, {2}];
  result = DeleteCases[Thread[{keys, vals}], {_, {}}];
  Map[If[Length@# == 1, #[[1]], #] &, result, {2}]
  ]
```

This works on both your test cases.

For the second one:

```
list = {{{15, "->", 15}, 3}, {{15, "->", 15}, 8}, {{16, "->", 16}, 2},
        {{16, "->", 16}, 3}, {{16, "->", 16}, 4}, {{16, "->", 16}, 5},
        {{16, "->", 16}, 6}, {{16, "->", 16}, 7}, {{16, "->", 16}, 8}};
commonAssociations[list]
```

> ```
> {{{15, "->", 15}, {3, 8}}, {{16, "->", 16}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}},
>  {{{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, {3, 8}}}
> ```

Explanation:
As I understand, the input is a list of pairs `{{key1, value1}, ...}`. First we group values associated to each key (`Merge[Association@*Rule @@@ list, Union]`).

Common associations I interpret as values common to more than one key. So I take all possible subsets of the keys `keys = Rest@Subsets[Keys@assoc];` then get the values associated to each of these subsets `Map[assoc, keys, {2}]` then extract those values, which where common for every key in the subset by taking the intersection of the lists of values (`Intersection@@@`).

Finally, I delete associations to subsets of keys that had no common element (that is `{ set_of_keys, {(*no values here*)}}`) which are matched by the pattern `{_, {}}`) and then replace all lists of length 1 by their only element.

**Update 05.03.18**
My algorithm above, unfortunately, grows exponentially with the number of keys (there are `2^n` subsets of `n` keys). For the examples provided by OP the number of keys was quite small, but for a general solution a different approach is probably in order. Before going on, I'd acknowledge that I do not have a solution to this right now, but there is an alternative take to this problem which may be of interest: let's take a new example list that was provided in a comment:

```
list = 
{{{14, "->", 14}, 6}, {{14, "->", 14}, 8}, {{14, "->", 14}, 10},
 {{15, "->", 15}, 3}, {{15, "->", 15}, 8}, {{15, "->", 15}, 11},
 {{16, "->", 16}, 2}, {{16, "->", 16}, 3}, {{16, "->", 16}, 4},
 {{16, "->", 16}, 5}, {{16, "->", 16}, 6}, {{16, "->", 16}, 7},
 {{16, "->", 16}, 8}, {{16, "->", 16}, 9}, {{16, "->", 16}, 10},
 {{16, "->", 16}, 11}, {{16, "->", 16}, 12}}
```

I'm not particularly interested in what exactly the keys and values are, so I'll simply enumerate them with a helper function:

```
Block[{key, val, k = 0, v = 0},
  key[x_] := key[x] = ++k; val[x_] := val[x] = ++v; {key@#1, val@#2} & @@@ list]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 4},
>  {3, 7}, {3, 8}, {3, 1}, {3, 9}, {3, 2}, {3, 10}, {3, 3}, {3, 5}, {3, 11}}
> ```

```
MatrixPlot@SparseArray@Thread[% -> 1]
```

> [image: matrixplot]

So In a way, what the OP wants, is to pick out the largest sub-matrices of this matrix which are

- filled with ones.
- cover all the non-zero entries of the original matrix
- and no sub-matrix should be the sub-matrix of another one.

My algorithm failed here, since it generates redundantly e.g. the following associations:

```
{{1, 2}, 2}
{{1, 2, 3}, 2}
```

This is easily fixed by adding an extra step to my algorithm:

```
commonAssociations[list_] := 
 Module[{assoc = Merge[Association@*Rule @@@ list, Union], keys, vals,
    result},
  keys = Rest@Subsets[Keys@assoc];
  vals = Intersection @@@ Map[assoc, keys, {2}];
  result = DeleteCases[Thread[{keys, vals}], {_, {}}];
  result = Union@@@GroupBy[result, Last -> First];
  result = Thread[{Values[result], Keys[result]}];
  Map[If[Length@# == 1, #[[1]], #] &, result, {2}]
  ]
```

Since the order of key-value pairs doesn't matter, one can, at the very least, write a helper function that will automatically reverse the key-value pairs, so as to work with the subsets of the smaller set of the two.

**Update 06.03.18**
Having shown, that this problem amounts to selecting a number of submatrices, I find that

- [Given a large binary matrix, find the largest submatrix containing non-zero elements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108299/26956)

is very relevant here. However, I still do not see a trivial way to move forward here.

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen so far. The only problem is if list = {{{14, "->", 14}, 6}, {{14, "->", 14}, 8}, {{14, "->", 14}, 
  10}, {{15, "->", 15}, 3}, {{15, "->", 15}, 8}, {{15, "->", 15}, 
  11}, {{16, "->", 16}, 2}, {{16, "->", 16}, 3}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
  4}, {{16, "->", 16}, 5}, {{16, "->", 16}, 6}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
  7}, {{16, "->", 16}, 8}, {{16, "->", 16}, 9}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
  10}, {{16, "->", 16}, 11}, {{16, "->", 16}, 12}},   it includes {{{14, "->", 14}, {15, "->", 15}}, 8} and {{{14, "->", 14}, {15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, 8}}, only the later is desired.

Comment: Thank you, LLIAMnYP. Your solution is accepted. The bounty is yours.

Comment: @Phillip I think I see what you mean, but I don't have MMA handy right now. I'll check it out Monday.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I have been able to further process the output of this answer to obtain what I want to see. I would be interested to see your final solution.

Comment: @PhillipDukes I've added a fix, but in general, this problem is more difficult than seems at first.

Comment: Thank you @LLIAMnYP. Do you have any understanding for why this should be so difficult?

Comment: @PhillipDukes I tried to give an explanation for this in the update. In general, there are `n` keys and `m` values which gives `(2^n-1)(2^m-1)` possible submatrices, i.e. the size of the problem grows exponentially with the size of the input. I suspect that the problem can be reduced to something like `O(n^2 m^2)` with a sufficiently smart algorithm (coming up with one is the hard part). I recall a somewhat similar question that was smartly solved by an application of linear programming. I'll try to find it.

Comment: Here it is, related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108299/26956

Comment: But your commonAssociations2[list2] gives `{{{{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, {3, 8}}, {{16, "->", 16}, {2, 3, 
   4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}}` whereas the OP EXPLICITLY STATES in the original question  that `{{{15, "->", 15}, {3, 8}}, {{16, "->", 16}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
   8}}, {{{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, {3, 8}}}` is  required. I thiink at this stage the OP should reflect on FSL Lyons' famous aphorism on the Irish question: every time the English came within sight of solving the Irish question, the Irish changed the question.

Comment: @tomd I *think* OP is mistaken there. After all `{{{14, "->", 14}, {15, "->", 15}}, 8} and {{{14, "->", 14}, {15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, 8}}, only the later is desired.` would suggest that `{{15, "->", 15}, {3, 8}}` is redundant. That's what you get if you're struggling to specify the problem. After all, my attempt at specifying it is also not great.

Comment: Fair enough, that is a reasonable interpretation. But now an additional problem arises. commonAssociations2[list4] gives `{{{"bird", "dog"}, {6, 8, 10}}, {{"bird", "cat"}, {3, 8, 
   11}}, {"bird", {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}, {{"bird", 
   "cat", "dog"}, 8}}` whereas the OP SAYS the required result is `{{"dog", "bird"} -> {6, 10}, {"dog", "cat", "bird"} -> {8}, {"cat", 
   "bird"} -> {3, 11}, {"bird"} -> {2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12}}`.  The OP also asserts that  "{"bird"} -> {12}" should be part of the expected result.  I asked for clarification and was told (apparently) that both are OK.

Comment: But I think your second interpretation is likely to be the correct one.

Comment: I also think it is reasonable that the OP provide clarification.  IMO that is not being done.

Comment: @tomd I'm not fond of the way the problem is specified. I don't have a rigorous definition for the core problem, let alone the specifics of the I/O formatting, but I found the former interesting, while I have little interest for digging into the latter.

Answer (score 4):

```
gather[x_] := {#[[1, 1]], #[[All, -1]]}& /@ Join[GatherBy[x, First], 
 GatherBy[{#[[All, 1]], #[[1, -1]]}&/@ Select[GatherBy[x, Last], Length@# >1&], First]] /.
 {{} -> Sequence[], {a_, {y_}} :> {a, y}}

gather @ list
```

> {{AA, 3}, {AB, {2, 4}}, {BA, {2, 5}}, {BB, 6}, {{AB, BA}, 2}}

```
gather @ list2
```

> {{{15, "->", 15}, {3, 8}}, {{16, "->", 16}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
>      8}}, {{{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, {3, 8}}}

Comment: yes this is close , but there are logical duplications and unnecessary {}.

Comment: @PhillipDukes, does the updated version work?

Comment: yes, this is great.

Comment: please see edited question.

Comment: @Philip, updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative approach. It relies on `Merge`. It works with the example, but I'm not sure it's fully general.

It's convenient to start with a list of rules:

```
rlist = Rule @@@ list
```

Here are the functions used in the merges:

```
fun1 = If[Length[#] == 1, #[[1]], #] &
fun2 = Sort[#][[-1]] &
```

Here's the main part:

```
List @@@
 Normal @
  Merge[{
   Normal @ Merge[rlist, fun1],
   Reverse /@ Normal @ Merge[Reverse /@ rlist, fun1]
  },
  fun2
 ]
```

Comment: please see edited question.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{AA, 3}, {AB, 2}, {AB, 4}, {BA, 2}, {BA, 5}, {BB, 6}};
list2 = {{{15, "->", 15}, 3}, {{15, "->", 15}, 8}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
    2}, {{16, "->", 16}, 3}, {{16, "->", 16}, 4}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
    5}, {{16, "->", 16}, 6}, {{16, "->", 16}, 7}, {{16, "->", 16}, 8}};

list3 = {{{1, "->", 1}, 8}, {{3, "->", 3}, 8}, {{10, "->", 10}, 
8}, {{12, "->", 12}, 8}, {{13, "->", 13}, 2}, {{13, "->", 13}, 
7}, {{13, "->", 13}, 8}, {{14, "->", 14}, 6}, {{14, "->", 14}, 
8}, {{15, "->", 15}, 3}, {{15, "->", 15}, 8}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
2}, {{16, "->", 16}, 3}, {{16, "->", 16}, 4}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
5}, {{16, "->", 16}, 6}, {{16, "->", 16}, 7}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
8}};

  fun[lista_List] := Module[{as1, as4,as5}
  ,
  as1 = GroupBy[lista, First -> Last];
  as4 = Select[Reverse@GroupBy[lista, Last -> First], Length[#] > 1 &];
  as5 = Merge[Association[Thread[Subsets[Lookup[as4, #], {2}] -> #]] & /@ Keys@as4, Identity];

  {#[[1]], Sort[#[[2]]]} & /@  Transpose[{Keys[#], List @@ Normal @@@ #}] &@ Merge[{as1, as5}, Identity]]


fun[list2]
```

gives me :

> {{15, "->", 15}, {3, 8}}, {{16, "->", 16}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,     8}},
>   {{{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, {3,8}}}

while

```
Grid@fun[list3]
```

gives me:

> {{{1, "->", 1}, {8}}, {{3, "->", 3}, {8}}, {{10, "->",     10}, {8}},
>   {{12, "->", 12}, {8}}, {{13, "->", 13}, {2, 7,     8}}, {{14, "->",
>   14}, {6, 8}}, {{15, "->", 15}, {3, 8}}, {{16,     "->", 16}, {2, 3, 4,
>   5, 6, 7,     8}}, {{{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, {3,     8}},
>   {{{14, "->", 14}, {16, "->", 16}}, {6,     8}}, {{{13, "->", 13}, {16,
>   "->", 16}}, {2, 7,     8}}, {{{1, "->", 1}, {3, "->", 3}}, {8}}, {{{1,
>   "->", 1}, {10, 
>       "->", 10}}, {8}}, {{{1, "->", 1}, {12, "->", 12}}, {8}}, {{{1, 
>       "->", 1}, {13, "->", 13}}, {8}}, {{{1, "->", 1}, {14, "->", 
>       14}}, {8}}, {{{1, "->", 1}, {15, "->", 15}}, {8}}, {{{1, "->", 
>       1}, {16, "->", 16}}, {8}}, {{{3, "->", 3}, {10, "->", 
>       10}}, {8}}, {{{3, "->", 3}, {12, "->", 12}}, {8}}, {{{3, "->", 
>       3}, {13, "->", 13}}, {8}}, {{{3, "->", 3}, {14, "->", 
>       14}}, {8}}, {{{3, "->", 3}, {15, "->", 15}}, {8}}, {{{3, "->", 
>       3}, {16, "->", 16}}, {8}}, {{{10, "->", 10}, {12, "->", 
>       12}}, {8}}, {{{10, "->", 10}, {13, "->", 13}}, {8}}, {{{10, "->", 
>       10}, {14, "->", 14}}, {8}}, {{{10, "->", 10}, {15, "->", 
>       15}}, {8}}, {{{10, "->", 10}, {16, "->", 16}}, {8}}, {{{12, "->", 
>       12}, {13, "->", 13}}, {8}}, {{{12, "->", 12}, {14, "->", 
>       14}}, {8}}, {{{12, "->", 12}, {15, "->", 15}}, {8}}, {{{12, "->", 
>       12}, {16, "->", 16}}, {8}}, {{{13, "->", 13}, {14, "->", 
>       14}}, {8}}, {{{13, "->", 13}, {15, "->", 15}}, {8}}, {{{14, "->", 
>       14}, {15, "->", 15}}, {8}}}

Comment: this is an improvement, but try list2 = {{{1, "->", 1}, 8}, {{3, "->", 3}, 8}, {{10, "->", 10}, 
  8}, {{12, "->", 12}, 8}, {{13, "->", 13}, 2}, {{13, "->", 13}, 
  7}, {{13, "->", 13}, 8}, {{14, "->", 14}, 6}, {{14, "->", 14}, 
  8}, {{15, "->", 15}, 3}, {{15, "->", 15}, 8}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
  2}, {{16, "->", 16}, 3}, {{16, "->", 16}, 4}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
  5}, {{16, "->", 16}, 6}, {{16, "->", 16}, 7}, {{16, "->", 16}, 8}}

Comment: @PhillipDukes what's the problem with it?

Comment: For {{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}} it should have {3,8}. I find the output to be more readable when displayed in Grid format.

Comment: @PhillipDukes try now

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear on what you want but I think this might be it, and fairly cleanly.

I'll start with more concise data to reduce clutter:

```
list = {{"dog", 3}, {"dog", 8}, {"cat", 2}, {"cat", 3}, {"cat", 4},
        {"cat", 5}, {"cat", 6}, {"cat", 7}, {"cat", 8}, {"bird", 7}};
```

Note the inclusion of `{"bird", 7}` as there is no analog in your example.

```
m = Normal @* Merge[Identity];
mr = m @ Reverse[#, 2] &;
rls = Rule @@@ list;

m @ rls
mr @ mr @ rls
```

> ```
> {"dog" -> {3, 8}, "cat" -> {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, "bird" -> {7}}
>
> {{"dog", "cat"} -> {3, 8}, {"cat"} -> {2, 4, 5, 6}, {"cat", "bird"} -> {7}}
> ```

My question to you is which parts of the second output line do you want to keep?

Comment: Try {{"dog", 6}, {"dog", 8}, {"dog", 10}, {"cat", 3}, {"cat", 8}, {"cat", 
  11}, {"bird", 2}, {"bird", 3}, {"bird", 4}, {"bird", 5}, {"bird", 
  6}, {"bird", 7}, {"bird", 8}, {"bird", 9}, {"bird", 10}, {"bird", 
  11}, {"bird", 12}},  should output  {"dog", "bird"} -> {6, 8, 10}.

Comment: @Phillip But nothing for `{"cat", "bird"}`, `{"dog", "cat", "bird"}`, etc.?  How is that determined?  I think I understand your complaint, that `8` does not appears in the list for `{"dog", "bird"}`, but that's an artifact of how I interpreted this, apparently wrongly.

Comment: Yes, your are right. I'm am just trying to concisely point out an example of an omission. The FULL output should be {{"dog", "bird"} -> {6, 10}, {"dog", "cat", "bird"} -> {8}, {"cat", 
   "bird"} -> {3, 11}, {"bird"} -> {2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12}}

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
atomizeSingleton = ReplaceAll[{x_} :> x];
```

The query:

```
list  // Query[{GroupBy[First -> Last] /* atomizeSingleton, 
     GroupBy[Last -> First] /* atomizeSingleton /* Normal /* 
      Map[Reverse] /* Association} /* Merge[Flatten /* Union]] // 
 KeyValueMap[List /* atomizeSingleton]
```

> {{AA, 3}, {AB, {2, 4}}, {BA, {2, 5}}, {BB, 6}, {{AB, BA},    2}}

Answer (score 1):

**(Edit)  Second Attempt**

*list*

```
(list // Rest@Subsets[DeleteDuplicates[#[[All, 1]]]] & // (Transpose[{#,
Intersection @@@ Join[# /. GroupBy[list, First -> Last]]}] /. {x_} -> 
   x) &) /. {{x__}, {}} -> Nothing
```

> {{AA, 3}, {AB, {2, 4}}, {BA, {2, 5}}, {BB, 6}, {{AB, BA}, 2}}

Or as a function

```
assocs := Function[x, (x // Rest@Subsets[DeleteDuplicates[#[[All, 1]]]] &
 // (Transpose[{#, 
      Intersection @@@ 
       Join[# /. GroupBy[x, First -> Last]]}] /. {x_} -> 
     x) &) /. {{x__}, {}} -> Nothing]
```

*list2*

```
assocs@list2
```

> {{{15, "->", 15}, {3, 8}}, {{16, "->", 16}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
>      8}}, {{{15, "->", 15}, {16, "->", 16}}, {3, 8}}}

*list3*

```
assocs@list3
```

> {{"dog", 8}, {"cat", {2, 7, 8, 17, 18, 23, 24}}, {"bird", {6, 8, 10, 
>      15, 17, 19, 24}}, {"rat", {3, 8, 11, 14, 17, 22, 24}}, {"man", {2, 
>      3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
>      21, 22, 23}}, {{"dog", "cat"}, 8}, {{"dog", "bird"}, 
>     8}, {{"dog", "rat"}, 8}, {{"dog", "man"}, 
>     8}, {{"cat", "bird"}, {8, 17, 24}}, {{"cat", "rat"}, {8, 17, 
>      24}}, {{"cat", "man"}, {2, 7, 8, 17, 18, 23}}, {{"bird", 
>      "rat"}, {8, 17, 24}}, {{"bird", "man"}, {6, 8, 10, 15, 17, 
>      19}}, {{"rat", "man"}, {3, 8, 11, 14, 17, 22}}, {{"dog", "cat", 
>      "bird"}, 8}, {{"dog", "cat", "rat"}, 8}, {{"dog", "cat", "man"}, 
>     8}, {{"dog", "bird", "rat"}, 8}, {{"dog", "bird", "man"}, 
>     8}, {{"dog", "rat", "man"}, 
>     8}, {{"cat", "bird", "rat"}, {8, 17, 24}}, {{"cat", "bird", 
>      "man"}, {8, 17}}, {{"cat", "rat", "man"}, {8, 17}}, {{"bird", 
>      "rat", "man"}, {8, 17}}, {{"dog", "cat", "bird", "rat"}, 
>     8}, {{"dog", "cat", "bird", "man"}, 
>     8}, {{"dog", "cat", "rat", "man"}, 
>     8}, {{"dog", "bird", "rat", "man"}, 
>     8}, {{"cat", "bird", "rat", "man"}, {8, 17}}, {{"dog", "cat", 
>      "bird", "rat", "man"}, 8}}

*list4*

```
assocs@list4
```

> {{"dog", {6, 8, 10}}, {"cat", {3, 8, 11}}, {"bird", {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
>       8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}, {{"dog", "cat"}, 
>     8}, {{"dog", "bird"}, {6, 8, 10}}, {{"cat", "bird"}, {3, 8, 
>      11}}, {{"dog", "cat", "bird"}, 8}}

*where*:

```
list = {{AA, 3}, {AB, 2}, {AB, 4}, {BA, 2}, {BA, 5}, {BB, 6}};
list2 = {{{15, "->", 15}, 3}, {{15, "->", 15}, 8}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
2}, {{16, "->", 16}, 3}, {{16, "->", 16}, 4}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
5}, {{16, "->", 16}, 6}, {{16, "->", 16}, 7}, {{16, "->", 16}, 
8}};
list3 = {{"dog", 8}, {"cat", 2}, {"cat", 7}, {"cat", 8}, {"cat", 
17}, {"cat", 18}, {"cat", 23}, {"cat", 24}, {"bird", 6}, {"bird", 
8}, {"bird", 10}, {"bird", 15}, {"bird", 17}, {"bird", 
19}, {"bird", 24}, {"rat", 3}, {"rat", 8}, {"rat", 11}, {"rat", 
14}, {"rat", 17}, {"rat", 22}, {"rat", 24}, {"man", 2}, {"man", 
3}, {"man", 4}, {"man", 5}, {"man", 6}, {"man", 7}, {"man", 
8}, {"man", 9}, {"man", 10}, {"man", 11}, {"man", 12}, {"man", 
13}, {"man", 14}, {"man", 15}, {"man", 16}, {"man", 17}, {"man", 
18}, {"man", 19}, {"man", 20}, {"man", 21}, {"man", 22}, {"man", 
23}};
list4 = {{"dog", 6}, {"dog", 8}, {"dog", 10}, {"cat", 3}, {"cat", 
8}, {"cat", 11}, {"bird", 2}, {"bird", 3}, {"bird", 4}, {"bird", 
5}, {"bird", 6}, {"bird", 7}, {"bird", 8}, {"bird", 9}, {"bird", 
10}, {"bird", 11}, {"bird", 12}};
```

**Original Answer**

(I still think this is the most reasonable interpretation of the OP question *as posted*.)

```
(list // KeyValueMap[{##} &, Merge[{KeyMap[List, GroupBy[#, {First -> Last}]], 
   PositionIndex[GroupBy[#, Last -> First]]}, DeleteDuplicates@*Flatten]] &) /. {x_} -> x
```

> {{AA, 3}, {AB, {2, 4}}, {BA, {2, 5}}, {BB, 6}, {{AB, BA}, 2}}

```
list // Merge[{KeyMap[List, GroupBy[#, {First -> Last}]], 
PositionIndex[GroupBy[#, Last -> First]]}, DeleteDuplicates@*Flatten] &
```

> <|{AA} -> {3}, {AB} -> {2, 4}, {BA} -> {2, 5}, {BB} -> {6}, {AB, 
>      BA} -> {2}|>

Comment: try {{"dog", 8}, {"cat", 2}, {"cat", 7}, {"cat", 8}, {"cat", 17}, {"cat", 
  18}, {"cat", 23}, {"cat", 24}, {"bird", 6}, {"bird", 8}, {"bird", 
  10}, {"bird", 15}, {"bird", 17}, {"bird", 19}, {"bird", 24}, {"rat",
   3}, {"rat", 8}, {"rat", 11}, {"rat", 14}, {"rat", 17}, {"rat", 
  22}, {"rat", 24}, {"man", 2}, {"man", 3}, {"man", 4}, {"man", 
  5}, {"man", 6}, {"man", 7}, {"man", 8}, {"man", 9}, {"man", 
  10}, {"man", 11}, {"man", 12}, {"man", 13}, {"man", 14}, {"man", 
  15}, {"man", 16}, {"man", 17}, {"man", 18}, {"man", 19}, {"man", 
  20}, {"man", 21}, {"man", 22}, {"man", 23}}